# Android Navigation not working properly with shared view model mvvm

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, navigation, viewmodel

I have two fragments that share same viewModel

`ShoeListFragment` that displays list of sheos with fab and `ShoeDetailsFragment` that let user add new shoe on fab click

In `ShoeDetailsFragment` user can click add or cancel. on add the the shoe will be added and displayed in `ShoeListFragment`

if user clicks cancel we will navigate user to `ShoeListFragment`.

Now in first run I tried to add new shoe in fab click it got added and displayed.
In second run I tried cancel button and I was navigated to `ShoeListFragment`.

However if in the same run I tried to add and then I'm navigated to `ShoeListFragment` I click on fab it got clicked and `ShoeDetailsFragment`  is getting called but the layout is not visible!

I mean the `ShoeListFragment` layout is visible only.

ShoeListFragment

```
class ShoeListFragment : Fragment() {

lateinit var viewModel : ShoeListViewModel
lateinit var binding : FragmentShoeListBinding
lateinit var parentLayout: LinearLayout

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater , R.layout.fragment_shoe_list , container , false)

    binding.fabAddShoe.setOnClickListener({
        Timber.i("fab clicked")
        findNavController().navigate(ShoeListFragmentDirections.actionShoesFragmentToShoeDetailFragment())
    })

    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(ShoeListViewModel::class.java)

    Timber.i(viewModel.mShoeList.size.toString())

    viewModel.shoeList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner , Observer { shoeList ->
        Timber.i("List shoe observer")
        displayList(shoeList)
    })

    parentLayout = binding.llParent
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return binding.root
}


override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    Timber.i("onCreateOptionsMenu")
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu)
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
}

// Menu item id must match the destination id to navigate there
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    Timber.i("onOptionsItemSelected")
    return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, requireView().findNavController())
            || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
}
```

ShoeDetailFragment

```
class ShoeDetailFragment : Fragment() {

lateinit var binding : FragmentShoeDetailBinding
lateinit var viewModel : ShoeListViewModel

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    // View binding
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_shoe_detail , container , false)

    // Data binding - shared view model
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(ShoeListViewModel::class.java)
    binding.shoeListViewModel = viewModel

    binding.shoeModel = Shoe("" , 0.0 , "" , "")

    //Observers
    viewModel.isCancelAdd.observe(viewLifecycleOwner , Observer { isCancel ->
        Timber.i("Fragment Cancel shoe")
        findNavController().navigate(ShoeDetailFragmentDirections.actionShoeDetailFragmentToShoesFragment())
    })

    viewModel.isAddShoe.observe(viewLifecycleOwner , Observer { isAdd ->
       findNavController().navigate(ShoeDetailFragmentDirections.actionShoeDetailFragmentToShoesFragment())
    })

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return binding.root
}
```

shared viewModel

```
class ShoeListViewModel : ViewModel() {

/* Should we make shoeList observing mShoeList instead of doing
shoeList.value = mShoeList in once we add new shoe?
*/

private var _shoeList = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Shoe>>()
val shoeList : LiveData<MutableList<Shoe>>
    get() = _shoeList

private var _isCancelAdd = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
val isCancelAdd : LiveData<Boolean>
    get() = _isCancelAdd

private var _isAddShoe = MutableLiveData<Boolean> ()
val isAddShoe : LiveData<Boolean>
    get() = _isAddShoe

var mShoeList : MutableList<Shoe>



init {
    mShoeList = mutableListOf(
        Shoe("Filla" , 40.0 , "Filla" , "Filla shoes") ,
        Shoe("Addidad" , 30.0 , "Addidas" , "Addidas shoes")
    )
    _shoeList.value = mShoeList
}

fun addShoe (shoe : Shoe) {
    _isAddShoe.value = true
    mShoeList.add(shoe)
    _shoeList.value = mShoeList
    Timber.i("In Add shoe")
}

fun cancelAddShoe () {
    _isCancelAdd.value = true
    Timber.i("In Cancel shoe")
}
```

I tried debuggin it , in second time this line execute in `shoeDetailsFragment`

```
 binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater,R.layout.fragment_shoe_detail , container , false)
```

until it reaches

```
 return binding.root
```

Then this got called

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater , R.layout.fragment_shoe_list , container , false)
```

That's why I think the shoe detail fragment is not visible.
But why this behavior happenned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that, your `isCancelAdd` value will be cached, so in the 2nd time immediately you'll get the event after navigation and you'll navigate back from the detail.

Usually for events you'll have two options:

1. Use a `SingleLiveEvent` pattern or a `Consumable`, to make sure events are not consumed multiple times. See this blog for more info: https://proandroiddev.com/singleliveevent-to-help-you-work-with-livedata-and-events-5ac519989c70
2. Use [SharedFlows](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow#sharedflow). I'd go with this, since this is now the recommended way and `LiveDatas` are on their way to getting deprecated